# How to pass instance variables into a Sinatra class

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm writing a gem with a bunch of classes, one of which is a Sinatra class. In one class, I parse a SQL files to create an array with a bunch of values that is assigned to an instance variable. I want to take this instance variable and pass it to my Sinatra class so that I can open a browser and display this information. However I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this. So far I have something like this:

**my_class.rb**

```
class MyClass

  def get_columns
    # ...a bunch of code that parses, and ends up with an instance variable
    @var1 = ['column1','column2']
  end

  def start_sinatra
    %x(ruby sinatra_class.rb)
  end

end
```

**sinatra_class.rb**

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'launchy'

class SinatraClass < Sinatra::Base

  def open_browser
    Launchy.open('http://localhost:4567')
  end

  get '/' do
    @var1 = @var1
    erb :index
  end

  post '/' do
    erb :submit
  end

  run! if __FILE__ == $0

end
```

Obviously I know this isn't correct. What I'm trying to figure out is how to get the values from @var1 from MyClass to SinatraClass so they can be uses in my index ERB file. Also, I KNOW my hacky `%x` command is not the right way to start Sinatra from MyClass, but I can't figure out any other way.  This doesn't work:

```
def start_sinatra
  start = SinatraClass.new
  start.run!
end
```

Because `run!` doesn't work unless you call it from the file itself (e.g. `my_sinatra.rb`).

Comment: No clue what you're trying to do, but to pass values to a command you're running, make them command-line arguments, and read them in the file you're running.

Comment: How do I do that? Can you give me an example? The thing is I'm not starting Sinatra from the command line. I'm using Thor, which starts off instantiating an instance of MyClass. MyClass then parses a bunch of data which goes into an instance variable array. Then I need my MyClass instance to start up Sinatra, pass that instance variable to it, and display the data I parsed in MyClass. I just feel like there has to be an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters to your sinatra application with:

```
def start_sinatra
  %x(ruby sinatra_class.rb "#{@var1.join ' '}")
end
```

and then pick them up in the built-in array called ARGV so when you want to use your `@var1[0]` you instead use `ARGV[0]`.

**Sidenote 1**: the code line

```
@var1 = @var1
```

isn't doing anything.

**Sidenote 2**: you don't need to `run!` inside your sinatra class. It will start anyway.

**Sidenote 3**: I don't understand what you are trying to do so there may be a better way. For example - calling sinatra on the command line may be a good thing. Or not. You are spawning a new process from your other Thor ruby class and it will wait until it is done - maybe this is what you want? The part where a browser is started may suggest that you want to wait for some user interaction before moving on?

**Sidenote 4**: it may be worthwhile having a look at a tool made for starting rack based application. Unicorn is a very popular tool for this. Who knows - there may even be a Thor-Unicorn integration out there.